# WiFi Data Sharing with socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect multiple devices via Wifi Direct and create a group owner so that the client devices can connect to group owner.
when group owner send or push a message then all connected client devices get this message at the same time.
Is this possible in Android ?
If yes, please provide me some documentation or sample code.

Comment: I'm not sure if this meets all your requirements.  But look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: I already tried [WifiDirectdemo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).that only works for pairing two devices and I could not find a way to do anything else. @paulsm4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in essence, you would just use the normal [Wifi Direct API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).

In essence, you would need to advertise local service in order others devices to know which device they should connect to. And the one that advertises should be the Group owner.

in-case you could decide who's the group owner, then use the creategroup function to create a group, then add local service to advertise it, and to make the advertisement visible, you would need to keep peer discovery active, until you get first connection.

Then with Clients, just do discovery and find the device that is advertising the service and make connections to it.

Then in GO, after each connection changed event, get first connection information to see that you are really a GO, and then get group information to see how many clients you have connected to you.Note that new connection can also cause disconnected event to be shown, thus prepare your logic to handle those situations as well.

With clients, once you get connected event, then get connection information so you'll get the IP address of the GO.

GO should have active tread always accepting incoming connections, so your clients can connect it, and your GO would get the IP addresses of the clients connected to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i am confused how can i implement it. If you give me any document or related sample code it will be very helpful for me.